# Combining Lucene Results with Entity Framework Results?

Tags: entity-framework, lucene, lucene.net

Obviously, changes in a database will not reflect what is in an index all the time. Is anyone using EF with Lucene and combining the results of a Lucene search with results form the same search in EF? I understand you would only want to pull back results from EF that are not in the Lucene results.

**Update:**

I guess the best way to handle this would be to first search the Lucene index and get a list of results, then you would do a search like this for EF:

Pseudo Code:

```
var result = (from ef in EntityFrameworkList
                      where !(from l in LuceneList
                              select l.documentId)
                             .Contains(ef.Id)
                      select ef);
LuceneList.AddRange(result);
```

For those who like method chains

```
var result = (EntityFrameworkList.Where(ef => !(LuceneList.Select(l => l.documentId))
                                                   .Contains(ef.Id)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We indeed followed the approach I suggested in the update. One thing to note is we only used this for displaying small lists of results and not for every type of search. For Full Text Search on larger documents we only used the Lucene results since we are not storing FTS data in our database.